# Spark Cassandra Connector Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/TableRef

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

```
Spark version:3.00
scala:2.12
Cassandra::3.11.4
spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.0.0-alpha2.jar
```

I am not using DSE. Below is my test code to write the dataframe into my Cassandra database.

```
        spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config("spark.jars","spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0.jar,spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0.jar,kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar,commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar,spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0.jar,**spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.0.0-alpha2.jar**") \
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")\
        .config('spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level', 'ONE')\
        .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
        .getOrCreate()

    streamingInputDF = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.56.1:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "def") \
        .load()
##Dataset operations

    def write_to_cassandra(streaming_df,E):
    streaming_df\
        .write \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .options(table="a", keyspace="abc") \
         .save()
       
    q1 =sites_flat.writeStream \
    .outputMode('update') \
    .foreachBatch(write_to_cassandra) \
    .start()
q1.awaitTermination()
```

I am able to do some operations to dataframe and print it to the console but I am not able to save or even read it from my Cassandra database. The error i am getting is:

```
      File "C:\opt\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/TableRef
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource$.TableRefAndOptions(DefaultSource.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
```

I have tried with other cassandra connector version(2.5) but getting the same error
Please help!!!

Comment: you don't need foreachbatch - you can write directly to Cassandra from stream - just specifiy `format`, ...

Comment: also, if you just need to move data to Cassandra from Kafka, look to Kafka Connector: https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `spark.jars` options that includes only provided jars into the classpath.  But the `TableRef` case class is in the `spark-cassandra-connector-driver` package that is dependency for `spark-cassandra-connector`. To fix this problem, it's better to start the `pyspark` or `spark-submit` with `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0-alpha2` (same for kafka support) - in this case Spark will fetch all necessary dependencies & put them into classpath.

P.S. With `alpha2` release you may get problems with fetching some dependencies, like, `ffi`, `groovy`, etc. - this is a known bug (mostly in Spark): [SPARKC-599](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-599), that is already fixed, and we'll hopefully get beta drop very soon.

Update (14.03.2021):  It's better to use [assembly version of SCC](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly) that includes all necessary dependencies.

P.P.S. for writing to Cassandra from Spark Structured Streaming, don't use `foreachbatch`, just use as normal data sink:

```scala
     val query = streamingCountsDF.writeStream
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Update)
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "webhdfs://192.168.0.10:5598/checkpoint")
      .option("keyspace", "test")
      .option("table", "sttest_tweets")
      .start()
```

Comment: I found my solution elsewhere, and I can confirm this: "Update (14.03.2021): It's better to use assembly version of SCC that includes all necessary dependencies."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem,try it :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

version compatibility is presumed to be the cause

Comment: No, he had the correct version, he simply didn't specify all jars...

Comment: but i try it can solve the problem,this is my code: https://gist.github.com/EthanDCX/6d7355103d56a2fad932fad06051cad6

Comment: his question is about specifically Spark 3.0 for which there is only one version - for Scala 2.12.  Version was specified correctly, the problem was that author didn't use `--packages` when submitting the job, and as result, no dependencies were pulled automatically